# Azure AD B2C: Custom Policy Error Related to msal

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

[image]I have implemented azure active directory B2C in one of my projects.
I have used the following technology stack for that :
.Net Core 3.1 WEB API
Entity Framework
Angular 8.
Currently, Azure AD B2C is working fine for authentication in the local environment. but it throws me an error in a dev environment when we renew the token.

I have attached a screenshot here.

it would be great if anyone helps me for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Karan and please use this sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp and make sure you are using app.UseAuthentication(); in Startup.cs file to avoid the 404 error.

Please let us know if still issue persists.

Comment: I have already added that.
 
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors("default");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseOData();
        }

Comment: Thanks @Karan. Could you please let us know the differences of local environment versus development environment? As you mentioned, Azure AD B2C is working fine for authentication in the local environment.